# How to get efficiently sum columns of TF-IDF represented by Sparse Matrix of TFIDF Vectorizer?

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am analyzing a data corpus using TF-IDF and I want to remove popular beyond standard stop words. 
One technique that is useful is to get the summazation of the TF-IDF score of all words and prune words based on the threshold.
However, I can't find a technique in Python to do so. Is there an implementation of this strategy in python?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
t0 = time.time()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
temp_5000_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "TF-IDF built:", total

idf_dict = dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), vectorizer.idf_))
sorted_x = sorted(idf_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for name,idf  in sorted_x:
    print name + "\t" + str(idf) + "\t" + str(round(idf * 2) / 2)
```

Comment: Would you be interested in other ways of  removing corpus-specific popular words?

Comment: You should look at the `max_df` param in `TfidfVectorizer()`